# Why dollar sign $ does ignore the query string in apache httpd.conf when rewrite URL

Tags: apache, url-rewriting, query-string, httpd.conf

I had installed a xampp to run my wordpress application, now I need to configura apache to rewrite the url request,I had added a section configuration into httpd.conf,here are the codes:

```
RewriteEngine on
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([a-z_-]+)/$
   RewriteRule /([a-z0-9_-]+)/$ /test.php?app=$1
</VirtualHost>
```

When it works the result like below

```
http://localhost/aaa/ ---> http://localhost/test.php?app=aaa ,
```

yes ,it is what I want .
But now I find when the request like  http: //localhost/aaa/?p=12, it had been rewrite too

```
http: //localhost/aaa/?p=12 ---> http://localhost/test.php?app=aaa
```

That means the `$` regex does not work, I am confused.

What I want is when the request end of `"/"` just like `http: //localhost/xxx/` it will be rewritten to `//localhost/test.php?app=xxx`, but others don't.

Comment: I think it is working.  `%{REQUEST_URI}` excludes the query string (the part after the `?`) - see [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)

Comment: That is the *intended* and *documented* behavior. The query is not part of the rewrite-rule regex check, that is only applied on  the [(rewritten) request URL(/file)-path](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/directive-dict.html#Syntax). So the dollar sign does work properly in your example. You probably now have a different question, so please first study the manual and try to find the right words to ask.

Comment: I have just seen the official document about mod_rewrite,now I know my question is a little silly.But thanks for your patient answer. @hakre

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you intend to rewrite `/aaa/` only and don't want to rewrite `/aaa/?p=12` i.e. any URI with query string then replace your rules with this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule /([\w-]+)/?$ /test.php?app=$1 [L]
```

`RewriteCond` line here will make sure to apply the RewriteRule only when query string is empty.
Also `\w` is shorthand for `[A-Za-z0-9_]` hence I replaced it in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your patient answer,the question caused by my %{REQUEST_URI} misunderstanding